# How can I save a web page with embedded images

Tags: html, image

I know how to embed images in a web page inline. That's not my question.

My question is for a web page that has images included the normal way, as links to a distinct jpg file, how can I save it where it creates a single html file where the images are converted to embedded images inline in the html?

Comment: "I know how to embed images in a web page inline" ⬅ Write software to take the HTML file you have, download the images, and output that.

Comment: I was proposing SingleFile but was downvoted without any comment. It looks like it was a valid solution for this issue... So I deleted my invalid answer. Good luck!

Comment: @check_ca I didn't down vote it.

Comment: @check_ca Thanks for the suggestion. That would be the best answer for me. Please consider to answer again.

Comment: @Ray I undeleted the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SingleFile for this (I'm the author). It can be run as an extension or from the command line, more info here: https://github.com/gildas-lormeau/SingleFile.

Comment: That is the best answer for me. Quality stuff. Thanks @check_ca!

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer, but you may consider the MHTML format (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML), supported natively by IE, but also available in other browsers via plugins.

Comment: It is annoying that mhtml is not standard, as it could largely replace pdf and word.  But it was created by Microsoft, and so must be rejected.